# FirebaseRecyclerAdapter not updating data automatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am using FirebaseRecyclerAdapter that comes with FirebaseAndroid-UI library and I assume that when the data will change on Firebase it will automatically refresh and update the RecyclerView.

My code is simple:

```
Firebase firebasePicturesRef = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Image, ImageViewHolder>(
        Image.class, R.layout.pictures_grid_item,
        ImageViewHolder.class, firebasePicturesRef) {

    @Override
    protected void populateViewHolder(ImageViewHolder viewHolder, Image model, int position) {
        super.populateViewHolder(viewHolder, model, position);
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(model.getThumbnailUrl()).into(viewHolder.mImageView);
    }
};
```

I have also tried to manually refresh the adapter using **notifyDatasetChanged** in the the **onDataChange** method:

```
firebasePicturesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (mAdapter != null)
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

    }
});
```

Am I doing something wrong? What is the fix?

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint into `populateViewHolder()` and see if that gets triggered?

Comment: Found the problem. I was calling `mAdapter.cleanup();` in onStop of the Fragment. Removing that it is working fine. I think i should do cleanup in `onDestroy` method?

Comment: Good that you're calling `cleanup()`! In general you should call `cleanup()` in the "opposite" method from where you create the adapter. So `onCreate()`<->`onDestroy()`, `onStart()`<->`onStop()`, `onPause()`<->`onResume()`.

Comment: Put your solution as an answer

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem, i was calling `mAdapter.cleanup();` in `onStop()` of the fragment. Removing it fixed the problem.

Instead of doing cleanup in `onStop();` it should be called in `onDestroy()`

As suggested by Frank:

In general you should call `cleanup()` in the "opposite" method from where you create the adapter. So `onCreate()`<->`onDestroy()`, `onStart()`<->`onStop()`, `onPause()`<->`onResume()`